# Show / Hide several items in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

When I click on **Item 1**, there are **item2** and **item3** which are displayed correctly.

[image]

Here is

[image]

My problem is that if I click on **Item A**,

[image]

All hidden elements are displayed, even those of **Item 1**.

[image]

Normally, I have to see **Item B** only?

I don't see how I should handle this?

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent {
  showMore = 'show More';
  hidden: boolean;
  toggle() {
    this.hidden = !this.hidden;
    if (this.hidden) {
      this.showMore = 'show less';
    }

    if (!this.hidden) {
      this.showMore = ' show more';
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" (click)="toggle()"> Item 1 </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden" *ngIf="hidden" style="color: green">Item 2</li>
  <li class="hidden" *ngIf="hidden" style="color: green">Item 3</li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" (click)="toggle()"> Item A </a>
  </li>
  <li class="hidden" *ngIf="hidden" style="color: red">Item B</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the link on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sdbuok?file=src/app/app.component.html), thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

All your elements are bound to the same variable, so it's expected that they will all be displayed.

A better way to handle this would be to have a component for expandable items that handles the `toggle` method and store its value of `hidden`

Something like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-expandable-item',
  template: `<li (click)="toggle()">
  {{name}}
  <ul *ngIf="!hidden">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{item}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>`,
  styleUrls: ['./expandable-item.component.css'],
})
export class ExpandableItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string = 'Expandable item';
  @Input() items: string[] = [];
  hidden = true;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  toggle() {
    this.hidden = !this.hidden;
  }
}
```

And you can use it like this where you want:

```html
<app-expandable-item name="Item1" [items]="['item 1-1']"></app-expandable-item>
```

Feel free to edit this to suit your needs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we really can't do this on one component? I am still too beginner to understand this.

Comment: You can, but you would need something like an array to keep track of which item is expanded, then your `toggle` would take a parameter indicating the index of the item to expand/collapse and flip its value.

Comment: @aagharaf Alternatively, if you only have these two pieces you are trying to expand and collapse, you could just have two variables: `hidden1` and `hiddenA`, for example.